# Odin stuck at "File analysis"

Tags: odin, samsung-galaxy-s-10

When I press "Start" in Odin3 3.13, the log just says:

```
<ID:0/006> Added!
<ID:0/006> Odin engine v(ID:3.1.1301)
<ID:0/006> File analysis..
```

Then it is stuck forever, with the desktop computer's CPU constantly at 30% and 0% disk usage.

The same happens regardless of whether I start Odin [then](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=755762) connect my device in "Downloading" mode, or whether I connect my device first and then start Odin.

**Question:** How to solved the problem, and successfully download the patched firmware?

My configuration is:
- AP: `magisk_patched.tar` produced by Magisk from the Samsung Galaxy S10e firmware `AP_G970FXXU1ASD5_CL15820661_QB23234096_REV01_user_low_ship_meta_OS9.tar.md5`
- Options: Disabled `Auto Reboot`, so that only `F. Reset Time` is left enabled.

[image]

Comment: your magisk_patched.tar might be corrupt

Comment: ... or maybe carrier/region of used rom does not match. try another one. at least (without warranty, might be a scam) there is a patched version of odin which ignores some checksums https://www.xda-developers.com/samsung-galaxy-s8-note8-bootloader-odin
https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3762572

Comment: @alecxs: Thanks! I had picked a region without thinking. Now I found out the CSC of my phone using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo so I am downloading the matching country's ROM at sammobile.com. I will let you know whether it works :-)

Comment: @alecxs: I downloaded (from sammobile.com) the ROM for my phone's region, and... turns out it is binary equal to the one I had tried yesterday. So I guess it will not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did 3 things, tried again, and it worked (I mean it got past `File analysis`). I am not sure which one of the 3 things did the trick, unfortunately. You might want to try them all.

- Run [SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe](https://download.highonandroid.com/file/Drivers/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe.html)
- Use a different USB port, for me COM7 instead of COM6.
- Get the ROM for my phone's region. It is binary equal to the file I tried yesterday, though, so I doubt it changed much.

Answer (score 1):

i found that you must use the correct version of odin. For example, if your md5 file made in year 2015, you need to use the same odin version of the year 2015 (odin v3.07)

Try this by myself and it works. May work for your phone too.